# how to install xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 in Mac OSX 10.6.4 Snow leopard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I downloaded xcode sdk as "xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg" and try to install it on my mac mini Mac OSX v 10.6.4 Snow Leopard. But when I stated installation this gives error that minium mac OSX v 10.6.7. 
Please tell me how to upgrade it 10.6.4 to 10.6.7 for free.
Or how to install it directly. In my system XCode previous version 3.2.4 is install. 
and it supports only iOS 4.1. I want to work on iOS 5.

Comment: You need checkout your `App Store`'s updates and update it. It'll download a new install file(near 2.0G) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update your OSX.

**Go to  > Software Update > Check for new software update > Install.**

Answer (score 4):

Go to *** > Software Update*** to run the updates for your computer.
You should then be able to install Xcode.